# Unexplainable Null Pointer Exception in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the following method and I have tried everything I can think off without success.

```
   private void showCustomListView(int year, int month, int day) {

        List<Transaction> mTransactionList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        mTransactionList = AppManager.getTransactionsByDay(year, month, day);
        DailyTransactionAdapter mAdapter = new DailyTransactionAdapter(getActivity(), 0, mTransactionList);
        dailyTransactionListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
```

Here is the context: I have an Activity : `Activity_A` hosting `Fragment_A`. The above method is called from the `onResume()` callback of Fragment_A and here is that o`nResume()` method

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //When the Fragment resumes set the shown date to today
        mYear = selectedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = selectedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = selectedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));

        showCustomListView(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            //After the view is created set the onclick lister for the
            //Change date button
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDatePicker();
            }
        });

    }
```

The data for this adapter comes from an in memory list like so. This is the code section from the **AppManager**

```
   public static List<Transaction> getTransactionsByDay(int year, int month, int day){
        List<Transaction> dayTransactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        List<Transaction> allTransactions = getTransactionList();
        Log.i(TAG, "Size: " + allTransactions.size());
        for (Transaction tempTransaction : allTransactions){
            if (tempTransaction.getTransactionDate().get(Calendar.YEAR) == year &&
                    tempTransaction.getTransactionDate().get(Calendar.MONTH) == month &&
                    tempTransaction.getTransactionDate().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == day)
            {
                dayTransactions.add(tempTransaction);
            }

        }
        return dayTransactions;
    }
```

This works fine as expected when I start the app as in run the app from the IDE (Android Studio) to the device. The problem comes when I start another Activity - Activity_B, after the above list running and visible, and in Activity_B I add an item to the in memory list and the size of the list goes say from 10 to 11.

When I now go from Activity_B to Fragment_A the app crashes with an NPE at the `showCustomListView()` method above. I have tried to clear the list, I have tried `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` all without success, it keeps crashing at that method only after I add to the list while the app is running, it will run fine after I restart the app.

What else should I try: Here some of the NPE

```
11-04 09:36:19.147    6464-6464/com.valuecardnfc.valuecardnfc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.valuecardnfc.valuecardnfc, PID: 6464
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.valuecardnfc.valuecardnfc.Models.AppManager.getTransactionsByDay(AppManager.java:80)
            at com.valuecardnfc.valuecardnfc.Fragments.DailyTransactionFragment.showCustomListView(DailyTransactionFragment.java:160)
            at com.valuecardnfc.valuecardnfc.Fragments.DailyTransactionFragment.onResume(DailyTransactionFragment.java:102)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1521)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:823)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.startPendingDeferredFragments(FragmentManager.java:1128)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1477)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
```

Comment: Can you add the code for AppManager.getTransactionsByDay? Specifically line 80 in that code is where the NPE is being thrown. My first thought is Android's cleanup mechanism is destroying and recreating an Activity or Fragment and the data is not being persisted

Comment: Its posted,  I am suspecting that it has something with Fragment callback methods

Comment: Which line is line 80? It must be this one right?: List<Transaction> allTransactions = getTransactionList();

Comment: `Its posted` Nothing in your question indicates what code is from the file AppManager.java, let alone which is line 80. You need to mark line 80 with neon lights and make it as obvious as people. Realize that members of Stack Overflow are offering their time freely to help other programmers. The easier you make it for us to help you, the more likely you will get the help you need.

Comment: Thanks, I greatly appreciate any help I can get with this> here is this snippet showing line 80 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15447938/TransactionList.JPG

Comment: Please mark the line of code in your question here.

Comment: Unless it is possible (which it is) that your list has null entries added to it. Then the ```tempTransaction.getTransactionDate()``` must be returning a null object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tempTransaction.getTransactionDate().get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

This has two possibilities for a `NullPointerException`:

1. `tempTransaction` is `null`.
2. `getTransactionDate()` returns `null`.

Since you use the return value of `getTransactionDate()` in multiple locations, you should create a new variable:

```
Calendar transactionDate = tempTransaction.getTransactionDate();
```

Now you can check if this `transactionDate` is `null` and you can reuse it in your `if` condition. You will also immediately know if `tempTransaction` is `null` because this line will throw a `NullPointerException` in such a case.

Comment: Great answer. The best bet is to run the app in debug mode and step through the code. That'll at least tell you what is causing, then you can figure out why the Null is present in the first place.

Comment: Ok, checking it out now

Comment: Brilliant, it definitely took care of the null exception but its not returning the last item added to the list, I will work through that on own, Thanks for the answer

Comment: @ValOkafor All NPEs are clearly explained by the error message. I hope you have learned how to read them and figure out the problem on your own in the future.